# How to bring Catalog page default sidebar to Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layout

I'm using Codazon Fastest Theme (food-drink) variant. I have enabled `layout="2columns-left"` in `/app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/food_drink/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Now all products have sidebar enabled. But it is empty. I can add widgets like static block and it shows up there. 
[image: product page empty sidebar]

But I need the default sidebar with filters to be shown there
[image: default sidebar]

How can I bring the default sidebar shown in the catalog listing pages to the product detail page?

Comment: check this file and `catalog_category_view.xml`. i think removed using xml code

Comment: I checked the ````catalog_category_view.xml```` file, there is no mention of sidebar at all